# How to perform e2e tests in cypress for oauth2 google login?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

Cypress doesn't allow redirecting to 3rd party sites, so it blocks login on gmail.

I've set `{ "chromeWebSecurity": false }` in `cypress.json` and also tried pretty much every workaround specified [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/715) but nothing worked yet.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Did you try following https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__single-sign-on

Comment: @jonrsharpe i've already seen that one before but i can't seem to do it in the context of login on gmail. Did you find any success on trying to do login in oauth2 even if it's not gmail?